# How to implement a vertical UIPageViewController inside a horizontal UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uipageviewcontroller

[image]

I want to adjust my `UIPageViewController` to work like in the image, currently **1b** is able to go **2a** etc. What do i need to do to lock the direction like in the image? Did i forget anything or am i using the wrong logic. Any tip would help a lot!

**Note** the vertical `UIPageViewController` is inside the horizontal `UIPageViewController`

**Horizontal UIPageViewController code**

```
class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController , UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var pages = [UIViewController]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self

    let page1: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page1")
    let page2: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page2")
    let page3: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page3")


    pages.append(page1)
    pages.append(page2)
    pages.append(page3)


    setViewControllers([page2], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {


    let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!


    let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)


    if (previousIndex > 0)
    {
        return nil
    }



    return pages[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!
    let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)


    if (nextIndex < 1)

    {
        return nil
    }

    return pages[nextIndex]

}
```

**Vertical UIPageViewController code**

```
class upAndDownViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var pages = [UIViewController]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self

    let midPage: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("midPage")
    let topPage: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("topPage")



    pages.append(midPage)
    pages.append(topPage)



    setViewControllers([midPage], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)




}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {


    let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!
    let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)


    if (nextIndex < 1)
    {
        return nil
    }

    return pages[nextIndex]
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!


    let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)


    if (previousIndex > 0)
    {
        return nil
    }



    return pages[previousIndex]


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I put the horizontal `UIPageViewController` inside the vertical `UIPageViewController`. That fixed it but for some reasons other ViewControllers opened inside the **TOP** vertical `UIPageViewController` are able to Page down, i will look more into that and probably fix it.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? I'm actually just attempting to do something just like this. What did your storyboard look like by chance, if I could ask? (Also, I realize this was forever ago and you may have trouble even recalling what you were working on here...)